# Multiple instances of an Activity running even with singleInstance, singleTask and noHistory=true

Tags: android, kotlin, android-activity, duplicates, instance

My application has chatting activity. Registered user can sen messages (chat) to other users.
The issue that I am facing is that it seems like every time the chat activity is opened, a new instance of the activity is created.
After opening the chat activity for the first time, chatting works fine.
Then back to the previous activity.
Then opening the chat activity, received messages are displayed twice.
After opening the chat activity third time, received messages are displayed three times.
The number of times opening the chat activity exactly matches the number of times messages are displayed. This number also matches the number of times Log.e is called in that activity.

I tried the following in the AndroidManifest.xml.

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance" 
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:launchMode="singleTop" 
android:noHistory="true"
```

And I also tried the following when opening the activity.

```
if(receiver_id != null && receiver_id != "") {
     val intent = Intent(this, ViewMessageActivity::class.java).apply {
          putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER_ID, receiver_id)
          putExtra(Constants.MY_ID, Constants.myID)
     }.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT)
      .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
      .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK )
      .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)

     startActivity(intent)
}
```

None of the above works for me.

The received messages are inserted into Room Database.
What is very strange is that if I print the messages in the DB, newly received messages are inserted the number of times the activity is opened.
Then after going back to the previous activity and opening the activity again, the message inserted many times are just gone except only one. That is,

```
Suppose the following are the messages in the DB.
   message1 - message2 - message3

Then back to the previous activity, and opening the activity again and receiving message4. 
   message1 - message2 - message3 - message4 - message4

Then back to the previous activity, and opening the activity again and receiving message5. 
   message1 - message2 - message3 - message4 - message5 - message5 - message5
```

Does anyone have a clue why?

Thank you very much for all of your answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this.
Chat messages have been added multiple times because I forgot to unregister the BroadcastReceiver when destroying the activity.
Following solved the issue.

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver)
}
```